# Problema con xdebug y netbean IDE 8.1 linux

Tags: netbeans, servidor

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy usando el **xampp 1.8** en **linux ubuntu 16.04**. Lo que esta sucediendo, es que cuando lanzo el **debug** no se me esta deteniendo en el punto de ruptura que estoy colocando a pesar que me el **debug** me dice que esta listo. A continuación les dejo los dato de la configuración para ver si me pueden ayudar.

**En el XAMPP**

```
[Xdebug]
extension = xdebug.so
zend_extension= "/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

**Imagen de la configuración del NetBeans**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estás usando la versión correcta de xdebug para tu versión de php?

Comment: Hola buenos días estoy usando la versión que se compila directamente del repositorio de Ubuntu la versión de php que estoy usando es la 5.6